# Module installed but error importing cartopy

Tags: python, conda, cartopy

This question has been asked many times in a similar fashion, but none seem to point to a solution/answer I need.
I have installed all that is needed for cartopy:
[image]

However, when I try to import the module in python:
[image]

I have installed cartopy using conda, and I will provide any other info needed to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Operating System are you on? (I would just comment but lack the reputation).

I just created a new conda environment (`conda create -n env_name`), activated it (`conda activate env_name`), and then just did `conda install cartopy`. I was then able to import it successfully in the python interpreter.

Details

- OS: Windows 10
- conda: 4.7.5
- python: 3.7.4

Comment: Whenever I attempt to install anything using conda, I get an error message (which I will now add to post)

Comment: Does the error message say anything else besides what you posted?

Comment: I have solved the error message and removed it from my post, I have solved it and have created the new conda environment, activated it, and installed cartopy, however I still get the same error message 'no module named cartopy'.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows 10, exact same as yours

Comment: I would check your path. It is possible when you enter the interpreter that you are using a different copy of python than the one located in your conda environment, in which case it wouldn't be able to find cartopy, unless it was installed in that python's environment. You could investigate by doing `import sys; sys.path` in the interpreter.

Comment: You can also do `where python` from the command line on Windows (`which python` on Mac, Linux). I believe the first one is the one that will be loaded when you just do `python` to start the interpreter.

Comment: I have found the locations and such, yet I have found that when I try to import cartopy from the conda command line, it works fine - so the issue is with python's directory perhaps - is there anyway I can redirect it to conda?

Comment: So when you do `where python` in the conda command line versus the windows command line, I'm assuming you get a different result for the top python copy?

Comment: Okay, you can just go into 'Edit the system environment variables' from the Windows search bar to modify your path directly. Basically, make sure that your anaconda version of python is listed before any other versions you may have installed. Also, note that you actually have two 'Path' variables - one for the system and one for the user. Your final path is your System Path + User Path. So anything in your user path will come after folders in your system path. I'd put both python versions (Miniconda and Anaconda) in your User path, with the Anaconda one listed first.

Comment: Could you show me/visulaise this? I am having issues with editing and adding these environmental variables, because they do not already exist, so I have made them, yet they are not movable (before/after)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198062/discussion-between-jon-strutz-and-jakethefake).